# Can't install any lib after using Chromedriver

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[VS Code PRINT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdukB.png)

I'm making a bot that send messages through whatsapp.

I installed selenium and chromedriver, but after installing chromedriver i simply can't install any lib for example: "pip install pandas". All i'm getting is this message:

"Starting ChromeDriver 115.0.5790.170 (cc0d30c2ca5577520c8646671513241faa0bc105-refs/branch-heads/5790@{#1923}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1691929125,846][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Address already in use (98)
IPv6 port not available. Exiting..."

i already tried to kill the service, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please tell us all steps required to reproduce this, see [mcve].

Comment: Are you using virtualenv for pip install? Which terminal do you use?

Comment: Well i'm using vs code. 
Not using virtualenv for pip insatll. 

First i installed selenium in the vs code terminal. Then, i downaloaded google chrome and the same version of chromedriver. After that i did put the chromedriver in the python file, did the code i'm gonna show on the image, and then tried to install pandas.

Comment: i'm using the image of the code, because i believe, the code itself is not the problem. There might be an issue with the chromedriver.

Comment: Try to kill the `chromedriver.exe` process:
`taskkill /F chromedriver.exe_process_id`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello Elie, i tried to kill the process using the following:
"ps aux | grep -i chromedriver" and it gave me this result:
pozzi       5369  0.0  0.0   6572  2432 pts/0    S+   21:52   0:00 grep --color=auto -i chromedriver

then i tried: "sudo kill -9 5369" and the result was: "kill: (5369): No such process"

then: "taskkill /F chromedriver.exe_5369" and the result was:

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 115.0.5790.170 (cc0d30c2ca5577520c8646671513241faa0bc105-refs/branch-heads/5790@{#1923}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1692061231,223][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Address already in use (98)
IPv6 port not available. Exiting...